# Cannot create project or tasks in activeCollab

Tags: php, activecollab

I have just installed and running activeCollab system. For some unknown reason, I cannot create any project or tasks, it pops up weird error alert in the right bottom. Can someone help please?

Thanks in advance!
[image: weird error]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a strange issue, I'd recommend reaching out to the activeCollab support team about the issue first.

If you'd like to investigate things yourself, I'd recommend [making sure the "debug mode" is turned on in the config files](https://activecollab.com/help/books/self-hosted-edition/debugging.html) and [reviewing the hosting environment requirements for activeCollab here](https://activecollab.com/help/books/self-hosted-edition/system-requirements.html)

It may also be good to be sure all the core files were uploaded correctly and have the right permissions -- of course these are just general suggestions without knowing more about what the debug info is telling you.

Hope this helps -- I'd be happy to look into it for you, our company ActiveLabs develops custom activeCollab modules and offers consulting but I'm confident AC team will for sure get you up and running, their support team does a great job and your license comes with a full year of support and updates.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by incorrect permissions on `/cache` folder when you have web interface + scheduled tasks triggered via PHP CLI. First step to resolve this problem is to upgrade to activeCollab 4.2.4. If that does not help (it should), try one of the following:

1. Reconfigure your scheduled tasks to use cURL to trigger task URL-s instead of PHP CLI to trigger task scripts in `/tasks` folder. Check out Administration > Scheduled Tasks page to see the example commands and task URL-s,
2. Use memory caching (APC or memcached) instead of file system based caching. This is something that we highly recommend (your activeCollab will run faster).

Answer (score -1):

Just 
chown -R 777 all the files and folders, the error disappeared.

Comment: You cannot chown to 777 ... you can chmod, but you should definitely not do this.